# How to code signing a Tauri app for windows

Tags: tauri

I just created a tauri app and I am now wondering How to code signing a tauri windows app , there is nothing in the documentation about windows signing it  contains mac specific code signing details

Comment: What do you mean? Here's perfectly fine documentation https://tauri.studio/docs/distribution/sign-windows

Comment: New link: https://tauri.app/v1/guides/distribution/sign-windows/